# Stream Internet radio using ffmpeg

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, internet-radio

i am a beginner at IOS Development now i make app that streaming internet and there was a problem that there is extinction that ios not support like .asf and .rm and there prifx that ios not support too like mms:// so after a lot of searching a lot of people told me that "use ffmpeg" and after a lot of wasted time i successfully build ffmpeg to my xcode now i am stuck because i don't how i use it .
so could any one tell me how can i use it please don't tell me use IFrameExtrator because i tried and i failed.

Comment: Show what you currently have to give users a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: i building ffmpeg well after that i don't know what i have to do so i need someone to tell me what is the next step